# Single Trigger for multiple events

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have two tables in my SQL Server database say `Trainer(TrainerID, Username, Password, email, .... )` and `TrainerPassword (ID, TrainerID, Password, CreationDate)`. TrainerPassword(TrainerID) refers to Trainer(TrainerID). Baseline of task is to track password changes of the trainer. I'm using Trigger on Trainer table.

Now the issue raises in how to fire the trigger for the events

- AFTER INSERT - Adding and entry to TrainerPassword after an updation/insertion happens in Trainer table.
- BEFORE DELETE - Deletion of record in Trainer table should delete references in TrainerPassword

Can both of these events implemented in  single trigger...?

Comment: Since SQL Server doesn't have **BEFORE** triggers, this will be impossible to do. Also, even if you create an `AFTER INSERT` and an `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger, those **cannot** be combined - two separate times of execution means two separate triggers

Comment: okay. thx.... any possible solution for this..?

Comment: The solution is: **two separate triggers**.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this...

### for Insert and update

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Trainer_For_Insert_Update
ON Trainer
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT INTO TrainerPassword (TrainerID, [Password], CreationDate)
  SELECT TrainerID, [Password] , GETDATE()
  FROM inserted

END
```

### for delete

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Trainer_For_Delete
ON Trainer
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DELETE FROM  TrainerPassword 
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted
                WHERE TrainerID = TrainerPassword.TrainerID )

END
```